# RVO/NRVO and public undefined copy constructor

Tags: c++, g++, copy-constructor, return-value-optimization

I'm fighting the following proposal now, and I want to know legal and for lesser extent moral arguments against it or for it.

What we had:

```
#include <vector>

class T;

class C
{
public:
    C() { }
    ~C( ) { /*something non-trivial: say, calls delete for all elements in v*/ }
    // a lot of member functions that modify C
    // a lot of member functions that don't modify C
private:
    C(C const &);
    C& operator=(C const&);
private:
    std::vector< T* > v;
};

void init(C& c) { } // cannot be moved inside C

// ...
int main()
{
    // bad: two-phase initialization exposed to the clients
    C c;
    init(c);

    // bad: here follows a lot of code that only wants read-only access to c
    //      but c cannot be declared const
}
```

What has been proposed:

```
#include <vector>

class T;

class C
{
public:
    C() { }
    ~C( ) { /*calls delete for all elements in v*/ }

    // MADE PUBLIC
    C(C const &); // <-- NOT DEFINED

    // a lot of member functions that modify C
    // a lot of member functions that don't modify C
private:
    C& operator=(C const&);
private:
    vector< T* > v;
};

C init() // for whatever reason object CANNOT be allocated in free memory
{
    C c;
    // init c
    return c;
}

// ...
int main()
{
    C const & c = init();
}
```

This compiles and links (and works) using recent g++ (which is the only target compiler) both 4.1.2 and 4.4.5  -- because of (N)RVO the copy-constructor is never called; destructor is called at the end of main() only.

It is claimed that the technique is perfectly fine, because there is no way copy-constructor could be mis-used (if it ever have been generated it would be linker error), and making it public prevents compiler for complaining about private one.

It looks really-really wrong for me to use such trick, which I feel contradicts the C++ spirit and looks more like hack -- in the bad sense of the word.

My feelings is not sufficient argumentation, so I'm looking for technicalities now.

**Please don't post textbook C++ stuff here:**

- I'm aware of "The Rule of Three" and have read through 12.8/15 and 12.2 of Holy Standard;
- I can use neither `vector<shared_ptr<T> >` nor `ptr_vector<T>`;
- I cannot allocate `C` in free memory and return it from `init` via `C*`.

Thank you.

Comment: I’m assuming move construction isn’t a possibility for you?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: unfortunately no (g++ 4.1.2 is one of the compilers we should support, thus no 0x features).

Comment: "making it public prevents stupid compiler for complaining about private one." - not stupid compiler. The standard requires that the copy constructor is accessible even if the copy is elided, because copy elision is optional. So if it were allowed to be private then a program that relies on elision to avoid an error would not strictly conforming anyway, and in this case the standard requires that to be diagnosed. The compiler is helping you write portable code, admittedly against your wishes ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I know. Sorry, that was sarcastic part of "what was claimed". I've removed it from text to stop people pay attention to irrelevant details.

Comment: Another alternative: `init` could take an (empty) boost::optional<C> as by-ref parameter and then construct the object into this optional, returning a const-reference to the object inside the boost::optional. In this case the default ctor would also be private and `init` would be made `friend` of the C type. -- just an idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This compiles and links (and works) using recent g++ (which is the only target compiler) both 4.1.2 and 4.4.5 -- because of (N)RVO the copy-constructor is never called; destructor is called at the end of main() only.

While it may work with GCC, your code really has undefined behavior because it references a function that's not defined. In such a case, your program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required. Which means that GCC may ignore the rule violation, but other compilers may diagnose it or do something else strange.

So on those grounds, I would reject this way.

> My feelings is not sufficient argumentation, so I'm looking for technicalities now.

You want to have move semantics here. What about having this explicit?

```
class T;
class C;

struct CMover {
  C *c;
private:
  CMover(C *c):c(c) { }
  friend CMover move(C &c);
};

class C {
public:
    C() { }
    ~C( ) { /*calls delete for all elements in v*/ }

    C(CMover cmove) {
      swap(v, cmove.c->v);
    }

    inline operator CMover();

    // a lot of member functions that modify C
    // a lot of member functions that don't modify C
private:
    C& operator=(C const&); // not copy assignable
    C(C &); // not lvalue copy-constructible

private:
    vector< T* > v;
};

CMover move(C &c) { return CMover(&c); }
C::operator CMover() { return move(*this); }
```

Now you can say

```
C init() // for whatever reason object CANNOT be allocated in free memory
{
    C c;
    return move(c);
}

int main() {
  C const c(init());
}
```

Comment: can you please point me where does C++03 prohibit referencing undefined functions? Regarding move semantics, we don't want it *that badly* in this particular case: my question is more about why this proposal should be accepted or prohibited.

Comment: @Alex 3.2p3, the proposal should be rejected because it doesn't work portably. I understand your question, but I figured I would also tell how I would solve it in addition to answering your question.

Comment: Thanks, 3.2/2 + 3.2/3 clearly shows that that is UB. Also we've just figured out that MSVC++ 2008 and 2010 (which are not supported *now*, but you never know) reject this code.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that the compiler is under no obligation to elide the copy construction, especially if optimization is disabled (although g++ still elides the copy even without optimization). Thus, you're restricting portability.

Most likely if it compiles on a particular compiler it would function as expected though.

I know there are a ton of seemingly arbitrary/artificial restrictions on what you can do, but are you able to use a proxy holder for `C`?

```
class C
{
private:
    C() { }
    ~C( ) { /*calls delete for all elements in v*/ }

    // ...
    friend class C_Proxy;
};

class C_Proxy
{
public:
    C_Proxy() : c_() { init(c_); }

    // Or create a public const& attribute to point to this.
    const C& get_C() const { return c_; }

private:
    C c_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something you wont get out of peoples heads on technical reasons alone (aka "But it compiles and works on our compiler!"), so maybe a conceptually simpler approach might be a good idea?

If your concern is the constness ...

> ```
> C c;
> init(c);
>
> // bad: here follows a lot of code that only wants read-only access to c
> //      but c cannot be declared const
> ```

vs.

> ```
> C const & c = init();
> ```

the simplest (as in: no hacks and proxy stuff required) solution might be:

```
C c_mutable_object;
init(c_mutable_object);
C const& c = c_mutable_object;

// ... lots of code with read-only access to c
```